# Cannot override notion with package from unstable

Tags: nix, nixos

The latest version of `notion` is available in the unstable branch. I want my install of nixos 17.03 to use it. [Here](https://github.com/moaxcp/etc-nixos) is my configuration.

I override notion with pkgsUnstable.notion.

```
nixpkgs.config = {
  allowUnfree = true;
  packageOverrides = let pkgsUnstable = import (
    fetchTarball https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels/archive/nixos-unstable.tar.gz
  ) { }; in pkgs:
  rec {
    visualvm = pkgsUnstable.visualvm;
    notion = pkgsUnstable.notion;
  };
};
```

And I added `notion` to `environment.systemPackages`. I also have `services.xserver.winowManager.notion.eable = true;`

With this setup I can get `visualvm` updated from unstable but when I check the version of notion with `notion -version` I get `3-2015061300`. It should be `3-2017050501`.

How can I get the updated version of notion?

Comment: At the time of writing it's only available in the master branch of nixpkgs but hasn't made its way to unstable channel yet. You would need to wait for the unstable channel to update or install it from the master branch.

Comment: For reference the unstable channel is at git revision 799435b7cab97a39893a104999b3bc589e1172b1 which doesn't include the commit that updated `notion` to newer version.

Comment: @ppb awesome! I could add changes from my fork, nixpkgs, and unstable in this way. I just have to track each package as they go through the workflow.